# Removing lines from a file generated by curl that is called from two functions in my bash settings

Tags: bash, hosts

I am on Mac OS X and use http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/zero/hosts called by `curl` to help generate my hosts file.  A dir at /etc/hosts.d/* has several files:

```
1-warning // File of comments that explains how this whole thing works
2-hosts-original // The original OS X hosts file
3-adobe // Some Adobe hosts that flash talks to way too often
4-someonewhocares // The results of the `curl` command in my below function
5-development // Any local dev work I am doing to make my own quick domains
```

When `curl` runs, '4-someonewhocares' is written .  I use two functions because the host `curl` calls may be slow, down, broken, etc.

The two functions:

```
function write-hosts() {
    cat /etc/hosts.d/* > /etc/hosts;
}

function update-hosts() {
    curl http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/zero/hosts -o /etc/hosts.d/4-someonewhocares 2> /dev/null
    write-hosts
}
```

Every few days I call `update-hosts`, it writes a new '4-someonewhocares' file, when done, the function `write-hosts` `cat`'s all files in /etc/hosts.d/* and outputs it to /etc/hosts

I want to exclude a few lines from the '4-someonewhocares' file.  For example:

```
www.googleadservices.com
feedads.googleadservices.com
```

I think it best to do the line removal in the `write-hosts` function, as that will never be called until `curl` finishes up.  But I could also do it right after the `curl` command and before the `write-hosts` function.

I am looking for suggestions on the best location to strip the lines from the resulting '4-someonewhocares' file, and what is the suggested method to remove lines from the file.  Ideally I would put a '6-whitelist' file in /etc/hosts.d but then it gets complicated and I don't know how to exclude that from the `cat` command, though I could `cat` each file by name, as they are not going to change.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First create 6-whitelist:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts.d/6-whitelist
www.googleadservices.com
feedads.googleadservices.com
```

Now, modify `write-hosts`:

```
write-hosts() { grep -vhFf /etc/hosts.d/6-whitelist /etc/hosts.d/* >etc/hosts; }
```

#### How it works

The revised `write-hosts` copies all files from `/etc/hosts.d/*` but excludes any lines found in `/etc/hosts.d/6-whitelist`.  The `grep` options used are:

- `-f /etc/hosts.d/6-whitelist` tells grep to get a list of patterns to match from the named file
- `-F` tells grep to treat those patterns as fixed strings, not regexes.  Unless you need the regex feature, this speeds things up.
- `-h` tells grep not to print the names of the files that the lines came from.
- `-v` inverts the match so that only lines not in the whitelist are printed.

#### Notes

For portability, I removed the keyword `function`.  Bash does not need it and other shells will not accept it.